# Euler’s Method for solving ODE ( why the error is decreasing )

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode, differential-equations

I have a simple linear system with 2nd order of ODE.

[image]

The analytical solution of the system is

[image]

Euler’s Method is

[image]

Now I would like to solve the system and compare the approximated value with the true value. This is my code in Matlab

```
clear all; clc;

 t = 0;
dt = 0.2;
tsim = 5.0;
n = round((tsim-t)/dt);
A = [ -3 0; 
      0 -5];
B = [2;3];
XE = [1; 2];
u = 1;

fprintf('Time \t     Euler Value \t True Value  Error \n');

for i = 1:n

    % Analytical Method
    XA = [ exp(-3*t)/3 + 2/3; 
          (7*exp(-5*t))/5 + 3/5];

    % Euler Method
    dx  = A*XE + B*u;
    XE  = XE + dx*dt;
    X1(i,:) = [t, XE'];
    fprintf('%f \t %f \t     %f \t %f\n', t, XE(1), XA(1), (XA(1)-XE(1))/XA(1)*100 );

    t = t + dt;
end
```

The results are

```
Time         Euler Value     True Value  Error 
0.000000     0.800000        1.000000    20.000000
0.200000     0.720000        0.849604    15.254624
0.400000     0.688000        0.767065    10.307440
0.600000     0.675200        0.721766    6.451714
0.800000     0.670080        0.696906    3.849297
1.000000     0.668032        0.683262    2.229064
1.200000     0.667213        0.675775    1.266957
1.400000     0.666885        0.671665    0.711675
1.600000     0.666754        0.669410    0.396748
1.800000     0.666702        0.668172    0.220089
2.000000     0.666681        0.667493    0.121690
2.200000     0.666672        0.667120    0.067134
2.400000     0.666669        0.666916    0.036980
2.600000     0.666668        0.666803    0.020348
2.800000     0.666667        0.666742    0.011188
3.000000     0.666667        0.666708    0.006149
3.200000     0.666667        0.666689    0.003378
3.400000     0.666667        0.666679    0.001855
3.600000     0.666667        0.666673    0.001019
3.800000     0.666667        0.666670    0.000559
4.000000     0.666667        0.666669    0.000307
4.200000     0.666667        0.666668    0.000169
4.400000     0.666667        0.666667    0.000092
4.600000     0.666667        0.666667    0.000051
4.800000     0.666667        0.666667    0.000028
```

My question is why the error is decreasing ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on math.stackexchange.com. (don't worry, this will get your question migrated to a place where there should be more people who are able to answer your question)

Comment: I don't mind my topic to be migrated. If you can do it then do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'Ve have made the following correction. If you calculate ´XE  = XE + dx*dt;´ then also the time has to be increased by ´t = t + dt;´:

```
clear all; clc;

 t = 0;
dt = 0.2;
tsim = 5.0;
n = round((tsim-t)/dt);
A = [ -3 0; 
      0 -5];
B = [2;3];
XE = [1; 2];
u = 1;
X1(1,:) = [t, XE'];

fprintf('Time \t     Euler Value \t True Value  Error \n');

for i = 2:n+2

    % Analytical Method
    XA = [ exp(-3*t)/3 + 2/3; 
          (7*exp(-5*t))/5 + 3/5];

    fprintf('%f \t %f \t     %f \t %f\n', t, XE(1), XA(1), (XA(1)-XE(1))/XA(1)*100 );

    % Euler Method
    dx  = A*XE + B*u;
    XE  = XE + dx*dt;
    X1(i,:) = [t, XE'];


    t = t + dt;
end
```

Now the output is:

```
Time         Euler Value     True Value  Error 
0.000000     1.000000        1.000000    0.000000
0.200000     0.800000        0.849604    5.838471
0.400000     0.720000        0.767065    6.135693
0.600000     0.688000        0.721766    4.678287
0.800000     0.675200        0.696906    3.114622
1.000000     0.670080        0.683262    1.929326
1.200000     0.668032        0.675775    1.145733
1.400000     0.667213        0.671665    0.662889
1.600000     0.666885        0.669410    0.377167
1.800000     0.666754        0.668172    0.212243
2.000000     0.666702        0.667493    0.118548
2.200000     0.666681        0.667120    0.065876
2.400000     0.666672        0.666916    0.036477
2.600000     0.666669        0.666803    0.020147
2.800000     0.666668        0.666742    0.011108
3.000000     0.666667        0.666708    0.006116
3.200000     0.666667        0.666689    0.003365
3.400000     0.666667        0.666679    0.001850
3.600000     0.666667        0.666673    0.001017
3.800000     0.666667        0.666670    0.000558
4.000000     0.666667        0.666669    0.000307
4.200000     0.666667        0.666668    0.000168
4.400000     0.666667        0.666667    0.000092
4.600000     0.666667        0.666667    0.000051
4.800000     0.666667        0.666667    0.000028
5.000000     0.666667        0.666667    0.000015
```

The max error is reduced from 20 % to 6 % by using the correct time stamp.

The solution converges to steady state conditions for t -> inf. The algorithm is obviously able to find this end value (where dx -> [0 0]). Just in the transient approach to this equilibrium there are differences between discretisation and true value. You could get a clearer picture on, whats going on if you plot the curves for these solutions (instead of just looking at the numbers).

Comment: In your correction, the initial values are ignored for analytical method.

Comment: If this answers your questions, kindly consider to check-mark this as the correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the correction. I forgot to put `fprintf` before the Euler method. My question is still the same why the error is decreasing even if I increase the step size? Is this normal?

Comment: I'm reading this book http://www.amazon.ca/Numerical-Methods-Engineers-Steven-Chapra/dp/0073401064 I haven't seen any example with Euler method that the error behaves like what I'm getting in my  above example.

Comment: The analytical solution converges to [2/3 3/5]. Also in the numerical Approach this point represents a stable solution (If you insert the values then dx becomes [0 0]). Conseqently the endpoint of both Solutions is the same. The closer you approch the stabel Point, the smaller dx becomes. Consequently the differnce between the analytical solution and the discretisation becomes smaller with time because dx is smaller.    This behavior is typical if both Solutions converge to the same stable endpoint.  If the solution of the ode dos not converge to a stable endpoint then the error can increase.